# Find the best fitting function for some experimental data

Tags: fitting

I am almost new in *Mathematica*, and so I have some problems that may appear basic for you. 
I am given a set of data taken from an experiment. I am supposed to find the curve that best fits them. The data are:

```
data = {{0.12, 1.51}, {0.12, 1.50}, {0.46, 1.51}, {0.51, 1.52}, {0.79,
     1.52}, {1.07, 1.55}, {1.41, 1.53}, {1.46, 1.51}, {1.73, 
    1.51}, {1.74, 1.50}, {2.02, 1.49}, {2.02, 1.47}, {2.37, 
    1.41}, {2.42, 1.40}, {2.70, 1.34}, {2.97, 1.28}, {2.97, 
    1.29}, {2.98, 1.28}, {2.99, 1.30}, {3.00, 1.28}, {3.31, 
    1.21}, {3.61, 1.17}, {3.62, 1.17}, {3.65, 1.18}, {3.78, 
    1.15}, {3.79, 1.16}, {3.93, 1.15}, {3.94, 1.17}, {3.94, 
    1.17}, {4.18, 1.19}, {4.18, 1.20}, {4.34, 1.29}, {4.48, 
    1.39}, {4.48, 1.38}, {4.60, 1.56}};
```

Originally, I was looking for a function of the form

$$a - bx - \frac{c - (dx - e)^2}{f - (g x - k)^3}$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,k$ are constants to be determined, but if you have better ideas for the function form, please inform me. 
The code I used is:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, (a - bx - (c - (dx - e)^2)/(f - (g x - k)^3)), {a, b, c, d, e,
    f, g, k}, x]
Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x , 0, 6}]
 , ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Green, PointSize[0.03]}]]
```

But I get a number of errors, like "First argument data in NonlinearModelFit is not a list or a rectangular arrow"
I am searching for such a function desperately for some time now, I would deeply appreciate any help I could get....

Comment: `bx` is a *symbol*, `b x` or `b*x` is *b times x*, fix that (with dx ) and you're on your way...

Comment: Ditto for `d x` versus `dx`.

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen that particular function? Is it known that the data in this experiment should have such a mathematical form? I ask because a 5th order polynomial fits the data pretty nicely, and with 2 fewer parameters. Of course, any relatively nice looking data set will fit some polynomial...

Comment: Yes indeed, I am told by my professor that this mathematical formula could be used, but I am not restricted to use this formula only....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[ data, (a - b x - (c - (d x - e)^2)/(f - (g  x - k)^3)), 
                       {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k}, x, Method -> NMinimize]
Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 6}], 
     ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Green, PointSize[0.03]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The graph you found is excellent, but I am not able to generate it in my computer. I get the error:  "Value of Method -> NMinimize is not automatic..." , "General::ivar: 0.00012257142857142857
is not a valid variable...." (the latter I got with four different numbers),  and General::stop: 
"Further output of General will be suppressed during this calculation."  Is there a problem with my version of Mathematica (7)?

Comment: @ArbërLl Version 7 is rather old,and I don't have it around anymore. I don't think it supports `Method -> NMinimize` The other error is possibly solved by restarting Mathematica

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your patience, you already did a great job for me. There is one more question, though. I just got Mathematica 9, and I managed to get the curve you showed, but what about the form of the model, what does this symbol (<<1>>)^2 and (<<1>>)^3 that appears in it mean? !

Comment: @ArbërLl Execute `nlm["BestFitParameters"]`. You'll never be able to program a single line of Mathematica code if you don't read the docs. Try reading the `NonlinearModelFit[ ]` help page. (BTW the docs aren't friendly at first. Keep trying)